# Advisor asking to cite his works in my thesis. Not sure if the right thing to do

Tags: citations, thesis, advisor

I am currently writing my thesis, and so far I've mentioned some well known related artcles focusing on a certain family of methods. My advisor has also published a similiar work, which is not influential or as diverse compared to other methods - the work also focuses more on utilization aspect rather than benchmark one.

My advisor wants me to mention his work - I feel it would be a little out of place in my thesis, unless I mention some older not necessarily state-of-the-art methods. What should I do?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that this is a master thesis. Aside from that, what feels wrong to me is not having a choice to comply or not with the request and treating citations as a currency. It's a small thing, but if it weren't my advisor I would probably refuse.

Comment: What kind of thesis is this? Bachelor, master, PhD?

Comment: Just cite it. If something is relevant, even not in the way you see it precisely,  I recommend being generous here. Being too stringent in your citation is not a good way to go, especially if it's your advisor. Nobody likes authors who are citation-parsimonious :)

Comment: @Mark it's master

Comment: Agree with Dilworth, just cite it. But first check if it isn't such that maybe your advisor knows something that makes his work cite-worthy, in the sense that it should be discussed a bit? Could your work be based upon his to some extend?

Comment: I'll discuss it with him. I'm afraid that mentioning my doubts will upset him.

Answer (score 1):

You are working on that subject *because* your advisor has worked on sth. similar, aren't you. His mentoring will have been based on *that work*. By not mentioning it you would be hiding valuable information from the reader.

Comment: At least where I got my M.Sc. from, the thesis document is supposed to indicate who the advisor was. That should be enough to indicate whose know-how was consulted for the thesis.

Comment: It's the same here. The front page of the thesis mentions who the advisor is.